# UnicodeDecodeError occurs when deploying to Google App Engine (Eclipse/Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I have created a web application using Java (Java 8) on Eclipse IDE (version 2019-06 (4.12.0)). When trying to deploy it to Google App Engine, the following error messages are shown:

> Beginning deployment of service [default]...
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Work\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\logging__init__.py", line 861, in emit
>       msg = self.format(record)
>     File "C:\Work\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\logging__init__.py", line 734, in format
>       return fmt.format(record)
>     File "C:\Work\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\log.py", line 337, in format
>       msg = super(_LogFileFormatter, self).format(record)
>     File "C:\Work\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\logging__init__.py", line 465, in format
>       record.message = record.getMessage()
>     File "C:\Work\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\logging__init__.py", line 329, in getMessage
>       msg = msg % self.args
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
>   Logged from file context_util.py, line 386

I guess there is something about the python file in my google-cloud-sdk, but I never edited or even did anything to it. Would it be a version problem? It seems that my application could be deployed successfully, but this error bugs me.

Here is my gcloud version:

> Google Cloud SDK 277.0.0
>   app-engine-java 1.9.77
>   app-engine-python 1.9.88
>   bq 2.0.52
>   cloud-datastore-emulator 2.1.0
>   core 2020.01.17
>   gsutil 4.47

Comment: I recommend you update the gcloud SDK to the latest version and try again.
This seems an issue related to your environment, could you please tell me a bit more about your setup? Which OS are your using? Also, you may want to try moving your code to a location where the path is smaller and try deploying again. It might be useful in order to troubleshoot this if you tried to deploy the same code from another machine

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and Java runtime is jdk1.8.0_221. I used Eclipse 2019-6  as mentioned above but I installed Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers 2019-12 to see if the problem comes from Eclipse. However the above error messages still remain, as I mentioned my deployment seems totally fine (it works on GAE).

Comment: Line 386 of context_util.py is in a `_CallGit` function that calls out to `git` with some provided arguments, and that specific line logs a debug-level warning that it was unable to call `git` with provided arguments. Does your path, or any files within your project, contain non-ASCII characters by any chance?